# Graphics encyclopedia

Tags: data-visualization, references

I have to build a multi-user web app which is about traffic measurements, prognoses etc. At this point I know that I'll use bar and pie charts.

Unfortunately, those chart types aren't rich in expressing all the data that I collect and compute.

I'm looking for a collection of graphical charts. It is very ok if I have to buy a book or anything else. I need to find some graphical samples with explanations in order to inspire me.

Do you know of any such resource? Do you have any advice for me?

Comment: Make sure to check out the questions with the tags on this forum about visualization, http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/data-visualization and http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/interactive-visualization .

Comment: @Andy W: ty for your valuable tips :)

Comment: I recommend [this paper](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&cd=5&ved=0CDkQFjAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fsvn.cluelessresearch.com%2Ftables2graphs%2Fkastellec_leoni.pdf&rct=j&q=dot%20plot%20gelman&ei=yvRcTv6WH8fZ0QGHzc2FAw&usg=AFQjCNEPzeqRD2mQle2YBZ4dn55tmtLv0g&sig2=LwHKo8PbXy18m41Af4S__Qdotplots) by Kastellec & Leoni.  Also, in my opinion [mosaic plots](http://www.childrensmercy.org/stats/definitions/mosaic.htm) absolutely dominate pie-charts.

Answer (score 8):

For an online summary, check out A [Periodic Table of Visualization Methods](http://www.visual-literacy.org/periodic_table/periodic_table.html).

Answer (score 7):

If you fancy R, you can see the [R graph gallery](http://addictedtor.free.fr/graphiques/).

Answer (score 6):

[Cleveland, William S](http://www.stat.purdue.edu/~wsc/). 1993. [*Visualizing data*.](http://books.google.com/books?id=V-dQAAAAMAAJ) ISBN 0963488406.

Comment: I am currently reading The Elements of Graphing Data, http://books.google.com/books?id=KMsZAQAAIAAJ&q. If you are familiar with it, do you know what the differences between these two books are (I can't seem to find a good description of either online)?

Answer (score 4):

**Systat** (Lee Wilkinson) was an early leader in statistical graphics software.  It always has had a [nice visual gallery](http://www.systat.com/solutions/ImageGallery.aspx).

Answer (score 3):

A visual [gallery of really creative graphics](http://gallery.wolfram.com/) (but without much organization, unfortunately) is available on the Wolfram site (*Mathematica*).

Answer (score 3):

I've also found good material at The Gallery of Data Visualization: The Best and Worst of Statistical Graphics, at
http://www.datavis.ca/gallery/index.php

Comment: +1 I love the ["Best Pie Chart Ever"](http://www.datavis.ca/gallery/images/fox-news-piechart.jpg)!

Answer (score 2):

[Visual explanations](http://www.edwardtufte.com/tufte/books_visex) or anything else by Tufte is inspirational.

Answer (score 1):

[A Tour through the Visualization Zoo](http://queue.acm.org/detail.cfm?id=1805128) (Heer et al., Visualization
 8(5) 2010) offers a particularly interesting overview of "innovative" and interactive techniques for displaying data.

On a related point, a good software for data visualization, including the aforementioned gallery, is [Protovis](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/), which comes with a lot of [examples](http://vis.stanford.edu/protovis/ex/).